# How to unlink a GIT Repository from Visual Studio 2022 without deleting the folder

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I cloned a GIT Repository into my local folder in C:\GIT\MyLocalGITRepo, using Visual Studio Professional 2022. Now before doing that, I realized that I had already used the "C:\GIT\MyLocalGITRepo" folder as a GIT Repo for another application called SourceTree. Now I want to be able to unlink this folder from Visual Studio, such that Visual Studio should not recognize this folder at all. I intend to keep this folder to be used by SourceTree but I do not want it to be visible to Visual Studio. How do I go about doing this? Would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Gary - any resolution? I have the same issue